# Star to Delta conversion with current simulation in Micro-cap error

Tags: dc, simulation, y-to-delta

Converted Star to Delta resistor circuit, but Micro-Cap dynamic DC simulation show similar, but different result.. 141,518 vs 140,498 V. Is it some kind of Micro-Cap error?
[image]

Formulas used in Matlab:

```
format long

Rj11 = 1045.525902668760
R5_ = 3600
Rj2_ = 400

Rj115_ = Rj11 + R5_ + ((Rj11 * R5_)/Rj2_)
Rj115__ = ((Rj11 * R5_) + (R5_ * Rj2_) + (Rj2_ * Rj11))/Rj2_

R5_j2_ = R5_ + Rj2_ + ((R5_ * Rj2_)/Rj11)

Rj11j2_ = Rj11 + Rj2_ + ((Rj11 + Rj2_)/R5_)
```

Result:

```
Rj115_ =

     1.405525902668760e+04


Rj115__ =

     1.405525902668760e+04


R5_j2_ =

     5.377297297297298e+03


Rj11j2_ =

     1.445927437641723e+03
```

Comment: Check your formula; it won't be a sim error.

Comment: https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2020/08/star-delta-transformation-delta-to-star-conversion.html

Comment: Yes, it is done exactly as described..

Comment: I used an online calculator and this is what I get: Rj11j2_ = 1561.6954Ω;_  Rj115_= 14055.259Ω; R5_j2_ = 5377.2973Ω

Comment: Rj11j2_ = Rj11 + Rj2_ + ((Rj11 + Rj2_)/R5_) - here was mine error - "+" instead multiply.... Silly me :) Thanks for help indeed!